# Updating a view using union clause in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a view named `viewA` and another view named `viewB`. The goal is to update `viewA` by appending data from `viewB`. But the name of `viewA` should remain unchanged. And the other requirement is that `viewB` gets updated hourly. So `viewA` has to get updated at the same frequency.

Here is my attempt;

```
create or replace view viewA as(

  SELECT *
  FROM viewA
 UNION ALL
 SELECT *
FROM viewB;)
```

But this is giving me an `Invalid create statement error`. Can I please get some help on how to meet above requirements. thanks

Comment: I don't think this will work. What's the definition of `viewA`? And then you want to change it to `viewA=viewA+viewB`?

Comment: This is giving an `Invalid create statement error` because you closing parenthesis is misplaced (after the `;`). Otherwise you would have a `View definition refers to view being defined: VIEWA`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need here is [Recursive views](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-introduction.html#recursive-views-non-materialized-views-only) as you want to create a view that refers to itself.